# Making font of Labeled function match that of Plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have the following code:

```
    Plot1 = Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 300}, 
   AxesLabel -> {None, "testing1"}];

Labeled[Plot1, "testing"]
```

I am trying to figure out how to make the font associated with the Labeled function match that of the Plot function. Does anyone know what font the Plot function uses?

Comment: Use the option `PlotLabel`, i.e., `Plot1 = Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 300}, AxesLabel -> {None, "testing1"}, PlotLabel -> "testing"]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is:

```
Plot1 = Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 300}, 
   AxesLabel -> {None, "testing1"}];
Labeled[Plot1, "testing"];
```

You can check the font in the following manner

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Graphics", FontFamily}]
```

> [image: arial]

And, hence, you should do `LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial"}` in the `Labeled` to match the font. You can do on top of that `LabelStyle -> {Small, FontFamily -> "Arial"}` to match the size. Altogether you obtain

```
Plot1 = Plot[Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 300}, 
   AxesLabel -> {None, "testing1"}, 
   AxesStyle -> {Small, FontFamily -> "Arial"}];
Labeled[Plot1, "testing", 
 LabelStyle -> {Small, FontFamily -> "Arial"}]
```

> [image: plot]

**Edit: to get more information you can use**

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Graphics"}]
```

> [image: info]